# Is there an RSS feed for podcast transcriptions?

Tags: support, feed, podcast, transcription

The podcasts are **interesting**.

Everyone agrees.

But since I'm *technologically*<sup>1</sup> deaf, I cannot listen to them.  Since there are some nice users that provide transcriptions of the podcasts, is it possible to have an RSS feed of them?

I just found out the [feed](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/rss.asp?ixWikiPage=4) for the different revisions of the containing page.

---

1. I don't have audio access while I would have time to read them

Answer (score 1):

Could you not subscribe to the RSS feed for the StackOverflow blog itself and get the transcripts that way?

**Edit** I should note that I completely missed the distinction between "transcript" and rundowns that are posted on the SO blog.

Comment: The transcriptions are linked from there though.

Comment: Yes, but that's not easily integrated in an RSS reader :-(