# CEO in Stack Overflow Podcast - Is there a transcribed version available?

Tags: discussion, blog, podcast, transcription

In the most recent Stack Overflow Podcast, announced in this [blogpost](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/21/podcast-a-chat-with-our-ceo-about-the-future-of-our-company-and-community/?cb=1), it is claimed that the CEO talks about the future of our company and community.

The title of the blogpost is:

> [Podcast: A chat with our CEO about the future of our company and community](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/01/21/podcast-a-chat-with-our-ceo-about-the-future-of-our-company-and-community/)

I don't mind listening to a podcast, when I have the time. Currently I don't and would like to be able to quickly glance through what is being discussed and read parts I find interesting/relevant when I have a few minutes to spare.

Is there anywhere this podcast is transcribed? I know in the past there were discussions about transcribing tools doing a decent job. It doesn't have to be an official SO transcription.

Comment: I already thought of posting a bug recarding deaf people and ability standards and welcomeness they claim.

Comment: @πάντα https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/335705/336163

Comment: You could always follow my Twitter thread breaking it down? https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1219608533928480768?s=21

Comment: Thanks for sharing @GeorgeStocker. Do I get the correct grasp if nothing important / ground breaking was discussed?

Comment: @Luuklag They put weight to the terms 'evolve' the community and 'improve' the software so that it reaches hobbyists and non professional programmers. There's a lot to unpack there.

Comment: It's a definite accessibility fail to not include transcripts, especially if these podcasts are Official Communication.  Transcripts also allow easier searching and future referencing.

Comment: @April--Un-SlanderMonica-- But not an uncommon one. I think there are plenty of "IT related" podcasts that have large audiences ... that go completely without transcripts.

Comment: I work in documentation for using accessibility technology in our organization's custom apps -- I'm all about accessibility everywhere now.

Answer (score 65):

My personal non-transcript, that tries to catch what is going on, and what kinda stood out.

- The CEO is really happy to have learned so much lately, and to work on such a great platform
- They are talking to "community members"
- He is so proud of that great platform, and the whole world using it
- There was real surprise by blunt feedback coming from "engineers"
- He was surprised that the Stackoverflow users he spoke with ... didn't know that stack exchange has *other* communities, that specialize in *other* important aspects in today's IT world
- So: they have ideas how to better *integrate* the one big with smaller communities
- There are 23 million "software developers" in the world, and 46 million people are coming to stackoverflow each month
- Beyond the foundation of the community ... there are the 3 different product lines (talents, the showcasing stuff, private teams).
- Large companies coming and building large "in house" "private teams" installations.

So, no surprise: it is mainly about IT related topics. It seems that only those smaller communities are worth mentioning that somehow relate to that.

If you hope to learn about the *relationship* between company and community: no need to listen in.

If you want to hear a lot of buzz words, and typical marketing "we are so good, and well positioned to grow ...": then sure, I have heard worse. It really helps that it is just 15 minutes. You can listen to the whole thing (even bump up speed a bit) without feeling the need to take a shower afterwards. But as said, for me, there was **no** "oh gosh, how many great things I learned today" moment after listening to the whole episode.

Comment: mumble... watch the podcast or listen to 15 minutes worth of Hatsune Miku singing Nyanyanyanyanyanyanya!... I will go with Miku.

Comment: One nitpick: Ben Popper was surprised by bluntness -- I don't recall Prashanth saying anything beyond an oblique reference to it.

Comment: Of course we are blunt.... otherwise we would make bloody mess all the time...

Comment: @BlueSoul Listening to the podcast resulted in learning me about Miku. Which, well, doesn't exactly spark joy for me either. Not exactly my kind of music. When the video isn't getting your coworkers going "that looks frightening, not going to look at this", then it is not worth listening too. ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i_uiI5LAlYI

Comment: @BlueSoul that sounds like a cat was involved. And rainbows.

Comment: Vocaloid is just a software - Hatsune Miku doesn't have a genre because every author use her voice for their own creation. Nyanyan is just a silly one. Try something like Cendrilion, Sebonsakura, World is Mine and so on.... Even the various Vocaloid voices are very different one from the other - Luka, Rin, Kaito, Miku.... everyone has a very different voice.

Comment: It's a much better investment to spend 1h listening to this Joel Spolsky interview ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY ) than to spend 15 minutes listening to that podcast.

Comment: Doing one doesn't exclude the other ... nobody asked for a transcript of that video. So far ...