# On podcasts, inclusivity and transcriptions

Tags: feature-request, accessibility, podcast

This originally started as a Discord discussion around the theme of the [inclusivity podcast](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/07/14/podcast-252-a-conversation-on-diversity-and-representation/) on the blog. Whilst this podcast in particular only really dealt with the theme of color, there are many other ways in which accessibility being limited is a problem, and inclusion is inhibited.

Would it be possible, even if the transcriptions are not *perfect*, to run the podcasts through an automated transcription service and provide those for the deaf/hard-of-hearing that also make up part of this community?

It would also benefit more than just the deaf/hard-of-hearing. For instance, I tend to read a lot more than I listen, and would find it easier to both consume the podcasts, and refer to them, with a transcription, even a partial one.

I've had the need to use [happyscribe](https://happyscribe.co) before, and even though the transcriptions are not always spot-on, it would be a lot better than no transcriptions, and even allow people to correct them down the line if need be. This could be a quick avenue to get this started.

Comment: It's also very useful for non-native speakers. Reading a foreign language is (for most people and languages) easier than listening.

Comment: @Glorfindel Absolutely - assuming the transcription worked. However, if there is a transcription, there's no reason native speakers who listen to the podcast wouldn't have the option to provide small corrections, too :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Provide official podcast transcripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335705/provide-official-podcast-transcripts)

Comment: Is the gist *run it through an automated transcription service*?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q Or provide manual transcription, or both. But provide *something* so nobody feels left out.

Comment: See [my answer on the other post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351156/51) for an update. And here is [the transcript for the episode on inclusivity](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/a-conversation-on-diversity-and-representation/transcript).