# Podcast transcripts are gone again

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, podcast

We've had this in the past: [Provide official podcast transcripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/335705/provide-official-podcast-transcripts/351156#351156)

Since then, the following podcasts do not have transcripts:

- [Ok, who vandalized Wikipedia](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/ok-who-vandalized-wikipedia)
- [The magic of metric, micro frontends, and breaking leases on Silicon Valley offices](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/the-magic-of-metric-micro-frontends-and-breaking-leases-on-silicon-valley-offices)
- [Who's afraid of a little merge conflict?](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/whos-afraid-of-a-little-merge-conflict)
- [Ben answers his first question on Stackoverflow](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/ben-answers-his-first-question-on-stack-overflow)
- [Where do game developers fit in the world of software?](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/where-do-game-developers-fit-in-the-world-of-software)

Would it be possible to:

1. Enable transcripts for all the links above
2. Enable this feature automatically so somebody does not need to post a bug report on MSE because there is no option for people who cannot listen to a podcast, be it right now or at all, to consume the content in the podcasts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with [episode 257](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/08/04/podcast-257-a-few-of-our-favorite-haxx/) (August 4, 2020), all transcripts are now being posted on the blog posts related to the [podcast episodes](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast/). That said, we have gone through and audited the podcast blog posts from the past couple of months and added in some transcripts that were missing.

I would like to be able to promise that this will never happen again, and that this will be fully automated, but I can't do that right now. The transcripts (while having some automation surrounding them) need to go through a couple of manual steps before they are posted (including review/edit for accuracy, and actually posting them). We recognize that we have been inconsistent with posting them, and are adding more checks to try to make sure that this wont happen.

I can though commit to our intentions to continue to post the transcripts moving forward. Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

---

> some absent transcripts
> podcast audience bereft
> blog posts fixed, check there

Comment: Would it be possible to identify the mechanism or source of preliminary transcripts that were produced automatically?  I've been correcting some interview transcripts that were produced automatically, and my brain is spinning, they're so horrible!  If there are better tools, I'd love to know about them.  (If the information can't be shared publicly, the mods on tex.stackexchange know how to reach me by email.)