# Podcast Episode Ep. 586 doesn't have a transcript

Tags: bug, status-completed, accessibility, podcast, transcription

The [transcript](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/developers-use-ai-tools-they-just-dont-trust-them) for this [podcast](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/07/04/developers-use-ai-tools-they-just-dont-trust-them-ep-586/) seems to be the episode notes - and while the title "Developers use AI tools, they just don’t trust them" is *interesting*, I don't do great with audio only podcasts, and would appreciate having transcripts to skim through.

I seem to recall the podcasts *should* have transcripts, so I'm hoping this is an oversight and is fixed.

Comment: Yes it's a bug, they [should have it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/351156/152859).

Comment: Worth to also link to the [transcript page itself](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/developers-use-ai-tools-they-just-dont-trust-them) directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should now be fixed.

[You can find the podcast transcript here.](https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/developers-use-ai-tools-they-just-dont-trust-them/transcript)

Thanks for the heads-up!